# Convert C# double to Pascal real

Tags: c#, .net, pascal

Help convert type double C# to Pascal real. The problem is that the types occupy different amount of bytes (8 and 6, respectively).

Comment: And how/where do you wish to convert? How is the real available to your C# code?

Comment: I had to write a byte in a file specific structures which operate the program in Pascal

Comment: Only use Delphi's 6-byte reals if doubles are too fast :)

Comment: Can't you use pascal double or extended? http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert C# double to Delphi Real48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539300/convert-c-sharp-double-to-delphi-real48)

Answer (score 1):

Real48 is already a legacy type since Delphi 3 or 4.  Use double as much as possible in your delphi code.